# Using the full SQL reference to the name of a database object causes my query to run 500 times slower

Tags: sql, sql-server, reference, subquery, query-optimization

Using the full SQL reference to the name of a database object causes my query to run 500 times slower.

When I use the full database.dbo.tablename.columnname, a few UPDATE queries take nearly 500 seconds to run, but if I edit one of the WHERE/AND clauses, with just the columnname, the query completes in less than a second.

I've compared the results of both queries and they output exactly the same data.

I had assumed that it is safer, and potentially faster, to fully specify the reference, rather than using just the column name.

What is strange is that I have other update statements in the same query, that reference the same column
in the same manner, and they do not suffer this issue.

An example of one of the queries is:

```
UPDATE database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE
SET database.dbo.LifetimeCount = (select count(*) from database.dbo.WORKTABLE as T1 
WHERE T1.retailer = database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.retailer
and T1.SalesTier = 1
and T1.Zdate < database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.Zdate)
```

A very uncomplicated query.
It took 500 seconds to run.
If I simply change the final AND clause to this:

```
UPDATE database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE
SET database.dbo.LifetimeCount = (select count(*) from database.dbo.WORKTABLE as T1 
WHERE T1.retailer = database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.retailer
and T1.SalesTier = 1
and T1.Zdate < Zdate)
```

It takes less than a second.

Perhaps it is some sort of indexing issue.

I am running MS SQL server developer edition 2019.
I am running the query from within the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on the system that is running the SQL server.
The query drops, recreates and then populates a secondary table, named SUMMARYTABLE, using UPDATES and SET statements, from a main table named WORKTABLE.

The main table (WORKTABLE) has over 7M rows, with about 30 columns of mixed date, varchar, int and floats.
The second table, SUMMARYTABLE is all floats and has about 50 columns, and is usually only a few hundred to a few thousand rows.

As I was building this multi UPDATE query, it gradually became slower and slower the more UPDATES I added.

Assuming I needed to index the database, I ran the "Database Tuning Advisor" from within the Microsoft SSMS.

After selecting the query in question for "Workload", and selecting the two tables in the database, and starting the analysis, it returned a list of indexes it recommended, to which I applied all.

This made the query run much faster, dropping from around 40 minutes, to around 3 minutes, total.

I was very happy, and continued adding update clauses to the query.
However, not long after, the query time blew out to over an hour.

I set "set statistics time on" to see where the slowdown was, and it was on some of the latest update statements.

So I re-ran the Database Tuning Advisor, applied any recommendations, once again, but the slowness persists.

While I can easily just use the column name by itself, what is the cause of this?

Comment: 1) Unless you are running your query against another database you shouldn't be using 3/4 part naming. You should always specify the schema, but thats all. 2) You should alias your tables, always, to something short and meaningful and then you only use 2 part naming for your table and don't repeat it.

Comment: Did you compare the execution plans? Did you check if maybe some of your updates were blocked? What were they waiting on?

Comment: Also, if you ran the tuning advisor and it suggested more indexes, did you just add them? While a missing index might help a very specific update, adding a bunch of indexes is certainly going to make every update work harder.

Comment: Very likely you are just seeing a bad plan coming up due to recompilation. You need to analyze your query plan

Comment: Also do you have a `ZDate` column on the `WORKTABLE` table?

Comment: @Dale K. Thanks. I'll start doing it that way.
I  just converted all of the queries from the full 4 part naming to just the column name.
The original complete query I left running last night - it ended up taking nearly 4 hours.
After changing it, it now takes 48 seconds. 
In regards to aliases, most of my statements all begin with 
`Update table SET SUMMARYTABLE = (select something from WORKTABLE as T1)`
Can I just set WORKTABLE as T1 alias, and then use T1 for the remaining 100 or so UPDATE queries, rather than setting the alias for each one? And the same as well for SUMMARYTABLE?

Comment: Check the documentation, anytime you reference a table add `AS xyz` and then reference the columns as `xyz.col1` from then on. Where xyz is 1-3 chars that have a meaningful relationship to the table. No you can't add a connection wide alias.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Bertrand. 
No, I didn't compare execution plans.
I'm not really familiar with looking at them.
So no, I couldn't see if any were blocked, or what they were waiting on.
They all completed, and returned the correct data, they'd just hang on each slow update. 
Re the Tuning advisor, yes, I reran it after adding a few more UPDATE queries and it did recommend a few more indexes, which I did add. 
It does seem to run consistently at under 1 second now though, so I hope I haven't stuffed up the indexing too much by just applying each and every recommendation.

Comment: You can share a link to the execution plans via https://pastetheplan.com. Execution plans are essential to answering performance questions

Comment: @Charlieface. 
First, I'm not really sure where to start analyzing my query plan. 
It is running consistently at under a minute now though, since using just the column name.
Second, yes, I do have a Zdate Column in the WORKTABLE table.
Most of the queries compare dates as one of the WHERE/AND clauses,  as in
`...and T1.Zdate < database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.Zdate`
(I left out the Z on the T1.date in my original question, apologies).

Comment: I'm not asking you to analyze it, just share a link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16 Run the query with an Actual Execution Plan -> Right click -> View XML -> copy into the above link. If you have that `ZDate` column then you are getting incorrect results as I outline below.

Comment: Thanks again @Dale K. 
I will, thanks. 
Just to clarify, if I set an alias via one UPDATE query, are you saying that I cannot then reuse that same alias on the next UPDATE query in the same .SQL file?

Comment: Queries are totally independent, you can whatever alias you like in each query... it just won't carry forward automatically from the last query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a `Zdate` column on the `WORKTABLE` The problem is that these are actually two very different queries

```sql
      and T1.date < database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.Zdate
```

What your first query is doing is making an outer reference, which means that the subquery needs to look at the outer table to get a value to compare.

```sql
UPDATE database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE
SET LifetimeCount = (
    select count(*)
    from database.dbo.WORKTABLE as T1 
    WHERE T1.retailer = database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.retailer
      and T1.SalesTier = 1
      and T1.date < database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.Zdate
)
```

The other version, because it has no table reference on the column, it is assumed it is referring to the inner query. It effectively becomes

```sql
UPDATE database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE
SET LifetimeCount = (
    select count(*)
    from database.dbo.WORKTABLE as T1 
    WHERE T1.retailer = database.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.retailer
      and T1.SalesTier = 1
      and T1.Zdate < T1.Zdate
)
```

Since `T1.Zdate < T1.Zdate` is a logical inconsistency, I would expect the whole subquery to be completely removed by the optimizer in place of a simple `SET LifetimeCount = 0`.

Which is almost certainly not what you expected.

As a rule, **always** specify table references in subqueries, due to this issue. And there is no need to specify the database name, your connection should be specifying that.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface.
I've uploaded the XML to that site, with two update queries.
The first one is the one that takes 401 seconds.
The second one takes about a second.
Here is the link:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy5KfM-b3

I know sfa about it, but from a look, the INDEX SEEK on the WORKTABLE, for the first one, seems to read 436 million rows, compared to on the second, which is about 350,000.

Comment: OK - well, it looks like the second faster query is as you suggest Charlieface.
The values of SUMMARYTABLE.ZDATE are all zeros..
Damn.
So now I'm back to wondering why this query takes so much longer to run than other very similar queries.
I'll compare execution plans of one of the fast ones, that also actually return data other than zero though, lol.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm back to an indexing issue?|
If I run the following two queries, the first one completes in under a second, the second takes nearly 500 seconds.
Both are on the same WORKTABLE and SUMMARYTABLE tables.
Both have 2 identical WHERE/AND clauses.
The only difference is that the column names are different, i.e. the first compares the T1.manger column to the summarytable.manager column, the second compares the T1.retailer column to the summarytable.retailer column. 
All the compared columns are varchar(50).

Comment: `UPDATE database1.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE SET database1.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.SalesTierCount = (select count(*) from database1.dbo.WORKTABLE as T1 WHERE T1.Manager = database1.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.Manager and T1.SalesTier =1 and T1.Zdate < database1.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.Zdate)`

and 
`UPDATE database1.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE SET database1.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.LifetimeCount  = (select count(*) from database1.dbo.WORKTABLE as T1 WHERE T1.retailer = database1.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.retailer and T1.SalesTier =1 and T1.Zdate < database1.dbo.SUMMARYTABLE.Zdate)`

Comment: Here's the plan for the two queries.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rypvD7Zb3

Any suggestion on indexes, or other options?
The INDEX SEEK for the fast one is around 200,000 Number of Rows Read compared to about 436 million in the second.
I do notice that Intellisense underlines both LifetimeCount and retailer, after copying them into a new blank query, despite both being spelt correctly, and having specified the database first using "USE DATABASE1 GO?

Comment: So you can see in the first set of plans that the inner subquery has 0 rows, which backs up my point. From what I can see of the second set: the `Manager` query is reading far less rows, because the `Manager` matches less. Both queries would probably be helped by adding `Zdate` as a third key column to the relevant index for `WORKTABLE`. A clustered index on `SUMMARYTABLE` would also be wise. I suggest you now make a new question, showing all of the following: the two queries, links to share their query plans, and all relevant tables *and indexes*.

Comment: Using window functions might help also, but without seeing all the info it's hard to say. Rough cardinality estimations for the subquery would also help: how many rows are there in `SUMMARYTABLE` altogether, and how many match per row of the outer table? Using this info would help us identify the right solution.

Comment: Thanks again @charlieface.
I appreciate your assistance and advice.
I'll make a new question and close this one.